# Does a CD-ROM drive also have a UUID like a hard drive?

Tags: cd-drive, uuid

Does a CD-ROM drive also have a UUID like a hard drive? How do I determine what the UUID is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't.

As [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) Ubuntu wiki says,

> 1. all filesystems should be specified by UUID= or LABEL= for each partition.
> 2. all physical devices should be specified by a symlink, like /dev/cdrom for a cd drive and /dev/disk/by-id/... for each physical
>      hard drive.

To find the UUID of devices, run the following command:

```
sudo blkid
```